# CGAL: Output ID of facet associated to halfedge

Tags: c++, cgal

This might be a very small issue, but I'm really wondering why it is not working. I'm trying to output the facet ID associated to every halfedge.

```
void MeshModel::printFacetsOfHalfedges() {
  for (Polyhedron::Halfedge_iterator j = P_.halfedges_begin(); j != P_.halfedges_end(); ++j) {
    int id = j->facet()->id();
    std::cout << "Facet is: " << id << std::endl;
  }
}
```

It starts with `Facet is: 0` and then crashes. If I remove the line `std::cout << "Facet is: " << id << std::endl;` the iteration runs just fine. I'm really wondering how this simple int output messes up the code.

I'm aware that I could also iterate over facets (and this works fine), but I need the halfedge<->facet association.

I'm using CGAL::Polyhedron_items_with_id_3 and initialize my facet IDs at the beginning:

```
void MeshModel::initializeFacetIndices() {
  std::size_t i = 0;
  for (Polyhedron::Facet_iterator facet = P_.facets_begin(); facet != P_.facets_end(); ++facet) {
    facet->id() = i++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the halfedge is not a boundary halfedge. In such a case `j->facet() == Polyhedron::Face_handle()`

Comment: You mean by ` if(i->is_border_edge())`? This tells me every halfedge is a border edge.

Comment: I made an error while building my Polyhedron. Now it's working. But I'm wondering in which order the Halfedge_iterator is iterating over the halfedges?

Comment: The are listed in the creation order except if you call [`normalize_border()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyhedron/classCGAL_1_1Polyhedron__3.html#a6ca5eddcfe19c5b69a500f39a0bfdbe5) that will but border edges at the end of the sequence.